# how to add datetime in mylog.txt file java

Tags: java, batch-file

i have following batch file java code, i want add date time also in mylog.txt anyone help me, i don't know how to add datetime with seconds in java batch.

```
@echo off
cd "C:\TreasureCliServices\"
start TreasureCliServiceCmd.exe

set JAVA_HOME=C:\jdk1.5.0_05

set CLI_HOME=c:\projects\utds\applications\cli
set CLI_LIB=%CLI_HOME%\lib

set CLASSPATH=%CLI_LIB%\commons-logging.jar;%CLI_LIB%\commons-logging-api.jar
set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;%CLI_LIB%\spring.jar;%CLI_LIB%\spring-core.jar;%CLI_LIB%\spring-support.jar;%CLI_LIB%\spring-remoting.jar
set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;%CLI_LIB%\utds-infra.jar;%CLI_HOME%\src\conf\spring;%CLI_HOME%\src\conf
set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;%CLI_LIB%\aopalliance.jar
set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;%CLI_HOME%\dist\cli.jar;%JAVA_HOME%\jre\lib\ext\comm.jar

set path=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%path%

java -Dport=COM3 -DbaudRate=9600 -Dparser=lgCliParser -DappContext=applicationContext-service.xml com.utds.cli.service.comm.CallerIdListener > mylogs.txt
```

> java -Dport=COM3 -DbaudRate=9600 -Dparser=lgCliParser -DappContext=applicationContext-service.xml com.utds.cli.service.comm.CallerIdListener > mylogs.txt

this line return save below data in text file, i want current datetimewith seconds also

```
got message '001 : 1234567885' got message '001 : 1234567885 ->  101' {phoneNo=1234567885, handsetId=101}
```

Comment: There are %date% and %time% environmental variables.

Comment: how to add datetime

Comment: you need to be more specific then that. Please edit your question and provide an example of what you need as output.

Comment: i edit my question

Comment: `echo %date% %time% >> mylogs.txt`

Comment: because only one time i call batch file and its automatically get callerid everytime

Comment: that is basically the only way to get the date and time into a text file using batch.

Comment: Batch has little to do with it. Ask Java gurus how to add datetim to a Java command.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off

set Year=%DATE:~10,4%
set Month=%DATE:~4,2%
set Day=%DATE:~7,2%

set Hour=%TIME:~0,2%
set Minute=%TIME:~3,2%
set Second=%TIME:~6,2%

rem Modify this line to fit your time format
set CurrentTime=%Year%-%Month%-%Day%_%Hour%_%Minute%_%Second%

echo %CurrentTime%

pause

rem > will simply overwrite the log file
echo (%CurrentTime%) java -Dport=COM3 -DbaudRate=9600 -Dparser=lgCliParser -DappContext=applicationContext-service.xml com.utds.cli.service.comm.CallerIdListener > mylogs.txt
rem >> will append to the log file
echo (%CurrentTime%) java -Dport=COM3 -DbaudRate=9600 -Dparser=lgCliParser -DappContext=applicationContext-service.xml com.utds.cli.service.comm.CallerIdListener >> mylogs.txt

pause
```

hope it helps